# how to configure Content Porter and its usage in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: tridion

I am trying to install, configure Content Porter to Tridion server.
Can any one share some links to explore more on it and its way of working.

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read the Content Porter documentation yet? You can find it at http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_ContentPorter_2009_SP1&lang=en-US.

Comment: Some good stuff here too: http://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/using-content-porter-2009-sp1-for-dtap-1.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Also check out part 2 of this tutorial on SDL Tridion World which describes the install for the server step by step: http://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/using-content-porter-2009-sp1-for-dtap-2.aspx